# CSS transformation using -moz-transform

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to make web page which would display two other webpages side by side using frames. The problem occurs when i try to zoom out a bit so that i could see more of the page. I am using -moz-transform but it I can't get the result i want.

I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkuyR.png) just with more zoom out on each individual page.
However after using transformation I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNZHz.png).

Code:

```
<div id="window1" style="height:60%; width:50%; float: left">
  <iframe style="-moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); transform-origin: 0 0;" id="thistory" src="http://www.15min.lt/" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="window2" style="height:60%; width:50%; float: right;">
  <iframe style="-moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); transform-origin: 0 0;" id="thistory1" src="http://www.15min.lt/" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `-moz-transform` is supposed to work.

What you can do is make the `iframe`s twice the size they are, and then scale them down with transforms. That would scale down the scrollbars, too, so you'll need to enclose scrollbar-less `iframe`s inside scrolling `div`s (`overflow:auto`, etc.) so you get normal-sized scrollbars.

Comment: It worked. Sort of. Any idea how to rid of white space left by transformation?

Comment: @kibirkstele I couldn't figure it out myself; maybe something with setting `transform-origin` to the top left corner (`0,0`)?